Is Gaussian Process Regression more suitable for limited amounts of training data than other methods?
In the field of machine learning for molecular properties, one sometimes has to deal with low amounts of (experimental) training data. I have heard some people advising me to use Gaussian Process Regression (GPR) to compensate for low numbers of training samples and these people argue with its inherent ability for prediction uncertainty estimation resulting from the Bayesian nature of GPR. Does this necessarily mean that GPR is more suitable than say neural networks for limited amounts of training data ? I know that it is more favorable for GPR if the training set size is small, but only because of scalability issues for large amounts of training data. Moreover, I could not find any literature that addresses this question.
If GPR is really good for limited training data, why exactly is this ? And is someone able to find a reference to back this up ?

Since you ask about NN's, I'll add that some recent papers have shown that: as you increase the number of nodes in a layer, a neural network converges to a GP with a particular covariance structure (see wiki for details) This suggests that one way to view finite Neural Networks is that they approximate the behavior of a Gaussian process. Useful because GP's cannot easily be fit to large datasets (cubic scaling).

The cubic complexity can be dodged in a few clever ways, most notably by inducing sparseness in the covariance/precision matrix or its cholesky factors, e.g. via Vecchia approximation, or using some other approximation like variational inference or INLA

Thanks for all the new information, I was not aware of the relation between NNs and GPR, this view makes GPR more illustrative for me.

That depends on a lot of factors, namely what kind of data you’re looking at, how you’re evaluating performance, and how well you can specify the covariance function.
For starters, GP regression isn’t necessarily Bayesian - you can absolutely fit a GP model in a frequentist framework (e.g. kriging in geostatistics). Also, if you’re fitting the model iteratively using train/test splits then any kind of inference or uncertainty quantification becomes extremely questionable since the procedure injects so much bias.
The advantage of a GP model in a limited data regime is that the structure of the covariance function imposes a significant constraint on the function approximation procedure. If you have a good idea of what your covariance function should look like, then that can compensate for not having sufficient data to fit something like a DNN, where that structure needs to be estimated from the data itself.
a well-specified GP model will probably outperform something like RF or XGBoost in situations where you have a lot of baked-in dependence (e.g. spatial correlation), and a good idea of what the dependence structure looks like.
There are also plenty of cases where a GP model probably won’t work well, regardless of how much data you have. Informally, GP models generally assume that everything varies smoothly and continuously across the support of the process, and that tends to work well when the process you’re modeling varies smoothly across some continuous dimension(s) like time or space.
If you’re working on something like a classification task with tabular cross sectional data, then where do you even stick the GP? The obvious answer is to assume that there’s some kind of latent dimension where the GP can vary smoothly, at which point you have to either specify the covariance of something that can’t be directly observed a-priori, which is hard, or infer the covariance structure nonparametrically, which requires a lot of data.

Thank you for your elaborate answer. In my case, I am using feature vectors that are specifically constructed to be used in normalized dot product or polynomial kernels (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.184115, p. 10). Can this be considered as information on the ''baked-in'' dependence ?

Molecular modeling is well outside my area of expertise, but I’d guess that yes, the underlying dynamical system constrains things to be fairly smooth, in the sense that the behavior of any one object will be fairly similar to that of its neighbors, with dependence decaying smoothly as a function of distance in the underlying spatial/temporal domain. Also note that ‘kernel function’ and ‘covariance function’ are generally equivalent terms in the context of GPs, with the former term being more prominent in ML literature and the latter more common in the math/stats literature
